# Can't add an inline keyboard to a user bot message

Tags: python, telegram-bot, pyrogram

I have a problem when creating a user bot on the Pyrogram API. When sending a message to my Favorites, I specify an inline keyboard object, but it is not sent with the message (BUT THE MESSAGE WAS SENT SUCCESSFULLY WITHOUT A KEYBOARD). It does not output errors to the console. Is it possible that my user bot was banned for something and therefore cannot send inline keyboards?

code handler:

```py
    @Client.on_message(filters.chat(cfg.donor_list))
    async def handler1(client: Client, event: Message):
        key1 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='123', callback_data='123')
        key = InlineKeyboardMarkup([[key1]])
        await client.send_message(chat_id = cfg.technical_channel, text = 'Message', reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(
            [
                [InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'buttontext', callback_data=  'btn1')]
                ]
            ))
```

query_handler:

```py
@Client.on_callback_query()
async def handler_query(client: Client, query: CallbackQuery):
    if query.data == 'btn1':
        print('answered')
        await client.answer_callback_query()
```

All handlers load SUCCESSFULLY
I really need your  help, thank you!

I thought about trying to change the user bot's token, but then I found out that the token cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Users cannot attach an InlineKeyboard.

Comment: Then how can I take a new message from a telegram channel and send it to my channel with a keyboard?

Comment: You can for example forward the message, which will show the "Forwarded from" header.